# Algorithm to match people with available appointments

Tags: algorithm

I need some help making a program that finds the best solution for everyone (more on that later).

---

```
6 7
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 1 0 0
2 2 2 1 2 2 2
2 1 1 1 2 1 2
0 1 2 2 1 0 0
1 2 1 2 0 1 1
```

The example given above is a problem that the algorithm is supposed to solve,
the first number of the first row indicates the number of people (6)
the second number of the first row indicates the number of appointments (7)

0 = the person doesnt have a problem with the date

1 = the person could choose these date if none else is available

2 = the person cant choose this appointment

Row = Person

Colum =  Available Appointment

What the program needs to do now is to find the best possible solution for everyone by choosing which colum  would be the best for the person's desire by arranging peoples appointments based on their choices

ex.

In the 3rd row the person can only attend the appointment on the 4th column since he cant attend to the other ones (2) which also makes column 4 complete and out of use for the other people.

---

The reason I need help with this is because I have no idea on how to approach this because this might be a simple example but since its an algorithm its supposed to work with dozens of peoples and appointments.

Comment: I don't see this as a sorting problem. I don't think you'll get anywhere attacking it that way so I edited it out of your question.

Comment: I don't think "the best" is not well defined in this question.  As such, counting the number of two's for each column and picking the one with the smallest number of two's would be a possible solution.  You could also count zeros and pick the column with the largest number of zeros.  If this is an algorithm question, the "best" should have been defined clearly.  If this is a real world problem that you face, then you need to come up with the objective that you are trying to minimize or maximize.

Answer (score 1):

The exercise is somewhat ambiguous, probably on purpose. My wild guess would be to sort the meetings by:

0. the highest number of possible participants, i.e., the lowest number of `2`s in a matrix column.
1. the lowest “badness”, i.e., the lowest number of `1`s in a matrix column.

   - Why not #`2`s: Because we don’t care about those who cannot participate at this sorting stage.
   - Why not #`0`s: Because we want to minimize the number of people inconvenienced by the meeting time, not (necessarily) maximize the number of people pleased with the meeting time.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

n_people, n_appointments = (int(i)
                            for i in sys.stdin.readline().split())
people_appointments = tuple(tuple(int(i)
                                  for i in line.split())
                            for line in sys.stdin)
assert len(people_appointments) == n_people
for appointments in people_appointments:
  assert len(appointments) == n_appointments

appointment_metric = {}

for appointment in range(n_appointments):
  n_missing = sum(people_appointments[i][appointment] == 2
                  for i in range(n_people))
  badness = sum(people_appointments[i][appointment] == 1
                for i in range(n_people))
  appointment_metric.setdefault(
      (n_missing, badness), []).append(str(appointment + 1))

for metric in sorted(appointment_metric):
  print(f'Appointment Nr. {" / ".join(appointment_metric[metric])} '
        f'(absence {metric[0]}, badness {metric[1]})')
```

Possible output (best appointment (by the metric described above) to worst appointment):

```
Appointment Nr. 6 (absence 1, badness 2)
Appointment Nr. 7 (absence 2, badness 1)
Appointment Nr. 1 / 2 / 3 / 5 (absence 2, badness 2)
Appointment Nr. 4 (absence 2, badness 3)
```

There are (of course) many other ways to evaluate meetings. Picking and defining a metric is quite likely an implicit part of the exercise.